# How does function call another function in Python

Tags: python

I want call function dynamically in Python, and code like as:

```
class A:
    def show1(self, x) :
        print x

    def show2(self, x, y) :
        print x, y

    def callfunc(self, f, args) :
        #TODO: call function f with args
        pass

c = A()
c.callfunc(c.show1, [1])
c.callfunc(c.show2, [1,2])
```

But I do not know how to call "show1" or "show2" in callfunc. Because "show1" and "show2" has different number of args, and "args" is a list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Same as always.](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)

```
def callfunc(self, f, args):
  f(*args)
```

Comment: And the language spec for that is [here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#calls).

Comment: Now this answer in python2.7 (inferring from using print as a statement) raises: `TypeError: show1() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)`.

Comment: @Hyperboreus: Hardly my fault.

Comment: Yes, but in which respect does your post answer OP's question, taking his code snippet into consideration?

Comment: @Hyperboreus: His typo is still not my fault.

Comment: I am not sure whether a missing operator (*) is a typo. If you are aware of it, why not just point it out. narf (Btw, same "typo" in your answer.)

Answer (score 1):

If you can pass function reference as the parameter, you can instead call the function directly. Here is a more flexible way to do this

```
class A:
    def show1(self, x) :
        print x

    def show2(self, x, y) :
        print x, y

    def callfunc(self, f, args) :
        return getattr(self, f)(*args)

c = A()
c.callfunc("show1", [1])
c.callfunc("show2", [1,2])
```

In this case, the function to be called can be determined and invoked dynamically.